# Return two different values in C (structs, lists)

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [returning multiple values from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829167/returning-multiple-values-from-a-function)

I'm trying to make a doubly linked list in C. I have a main function that calls another function to create nodes and build the list. I need this last function to return two different pointers (one to the start and one to the end of the list) to main.
Is there a way to use "**return**" to return two things? In this case two pointers.
I thought in returning a structure with two elements, the two pointers. But is there an easy way?

*This is how I call the function (insertacomienzo) in the main:*

```
primero = insertacomienzo (primero, ultimo, tamaniomax);
```

*(primero is a pointer)
And the function returns this pointer now modified.*

```
return primero;
```

**What I need is to return now two pointers, one is the one pointing to the start of the list, and the other is pointing to the end of the list.**

Thank you!

Comment: Pass by reference and set the values in the functions.

Comment: the code is pretty long (it's a work for the university), so it would be really confusing.. I will try to simplify this particular case and edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use InOut parameters to give back any extra parameter (this is how it's usually done in C).
InOut parameters are of type '**' instead of just '*' (in CPP they are of type '&*' but you don't have '&' in C)

Here is a prototye of a inout function

```
node* GenerateList(node* currentListItem,node** InOutLastListItem,int currentNodes)
```