# C - returning several values from method

Tags: c, arrays, char

I want to return few values from method:

```
unsigned long long *operand1, *operand2;
unsigned long long value1;
int operation=0;
```

I was thinking about putting those datas in char array and then retrieve them byte after byte.
Is this a good idea? How should I do this?
Or could you suggest anything else?

Comment: Why do you declare `*operand1, *operand2;` as pointers? c++ has by reference parameter support.

Comment: He said he uses C. Read the title.

Comment: @addy2012 He flagged it C++, so C++ answers answer this question. If he does not want C++ answers, he must remove the C++ tag.

Comment: "I was thinking about putting those datas [sic] in char array and then retrieve them byte after byte. " - No, unnecessary type-punning is not a good idea.
Also, are you using C or C++? *They're not the same thing.*

Comment: Alright, reopen and then close as dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829167/returning-multiple-values-from-a-function

Comment: Sorry, I added C++ tag habitually. I'm using C and I thing that struct can handle this problem.

Comment: I agree, define a struct, within an allocated memory area, then return a pointer to the struct/   I would also eliminate the 'pointer to long long entries by placing the actual value within the struct.  however if the function is to return different types at different invocations, the use a struct that contains a union, and the first field indicates which type is actual being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain C code you probably want to have something like

```
typedef struct params_ {
    unsigned long long operand1, operand2;
    unsigned long long value1;
    int operation;
} params_t;

int foo(struct params_* p) {
    int retcode = 0;
    // do something with p along operation
    if(p->operation == 0) {
        p->value1 = 100 * p->operand1 + p->operand2;
    }
    else if(p->operation == 1) {
       // ...
    }
    // ...
    else {
        retcode = -1;
    }
    return retcode;
}
```

and use it like

```
int main(void) {
    params_t params;
    params.operation = 0;
    params.operand1 = 5;
    params.operand2 = 42;
    if(foo(&params) < 0) {
        // Error occurred
    }
    unsigned long long result = params.value1;
    return 0;
}
```

See the [live demo here](http://ideone.com/5dJACJ) please.

Comment: this line: 'int foo(struct params_t* p) {' does not compile.  either remove the 'struct' modifier or (better) eliminate the 'typedef' and just declare a struct

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a `struct`.

```
struct my_struct {
    unsigned long long *operand1, *operand2;
    unsigned long long value1;
    int operation=0;
};
```

Comment: Shudder ... :-( . I can't see this ending up in anything good.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++11 then you can use `std::tuple`. See the reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple for examples of how to implement it.

This has the advantage over `struct` that you don't need to declare a new object for every set of types that you want to return.

Comment: Doesn't he meant to use plain C as he stated in the title?

Comment: It was tagged C++ as well so I wasn't sure which they are using