# My rand() function didn't work

Tags: c

this is my function: i need that every number that get random will be: one bigger than 50, one even, and one not even. i complied just with gcc and i'm using c99. It compiled well, but it when it print three random numbers it's print 0,0,and real random number. I want it to print for me three real numbers. thanks for who trying to help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define HIGH_NUMBER 100


int isValidNumbers(int num1,int num2, int num3);


int main(void)
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    num1,num2,num3 =isValidNumbers(num1,num2,num3);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",num1,num2,num3);    
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int isValidNumbers(int num1,int num2, int num3)
{
    int i=1,ans = 0;
    do 
    {
        srand (time(NULL));
        num1 = rand()%HIGH_NUMBER;
        num2 = rand()%HIGH_NUMBER;
        num3 = rand()%HIGH_NUMBER;
        if ((num1%2==0||num2%2||num3%2==0)&&(num1%2==1||num2%2==1||num3%2==1)&&(num1>50||num2>50||num3>50))
        {
            return num1,num2,num3;
            i--;
            printf("%d %d %d",num1,num2,num3);
        }
    }
    while (i);

}
```

Comment: `return num1,num2,num3;` isn't going to work. Use pointers instead.

Comment: Also, you have a printf after your return statement.  It will never be reached.

Answer (score 2):

Your function does not set the calling variables as you hoped for. You can't return more than one function value - and it makes no difference that you gave the same names to the variables in `main` and in the function - they are *different* variables, and as you wrote it, `main` just passes copies of those variable values.

Instead I pass *pointers* to those variables in this example. I also removed the return value of the function, since it now always returns valid values as your spec.

I removed `srand` within the function. It should be called once only, especially as I call the function 3 times in this example to show different results. If left in the function, all 3 calls would *probably* give the same result (unless a one-second timer boundary is bridged).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define HIGH_NUMBER 100

void ValidNumbers(int *num1, int *num2, int *num3);     // pointer arguments

int main(void)
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    int tries;
    srand ((unsigned)time(NULL));           // call once
    for(tries=0; tries<3; tries++) {
        ValidNumbers(&num1, &num2, &num3);
        printf("%-2d %-2d %-2d\n", num1, num2, num3);    
    }
    return 0;
}

void ValidNumbers(int *num1, int *num2, int *num3)
{
    do {
        *num1 = rand() % HIGH_NUMBER;       // write through pointer of passed var
    } while (*num1 <= 50);                  // number > 50

    do {
        *num2 = rand() % HIGH_NUMBER;
    } while (*num2 % 2 != 0);               // even number

    do {
        *num3 = rand() % HIGH_NUMBER;
    } while (*num3 % 2 == 0);               // odd number
}
```

Program output:

```
79 16 79
95 2  37
73 28 93
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning multiple values is not allowed in `C`. So

```
return num1,num2,num3;
```

this will not work.

---

You can use a `struct` with `3` numbers and return that instead. You can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3829206/1795279) for an example of how do go about it.

---

Also note that the statement inside `if` after the `return` statement will never get executed, and are thus useless..

```
return num1,num2,num3;
i--;                                // <-- this will never get executed
printf("%d %d %d",num1,num2,num3);  // <-- this will never get executed
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in C to return multiple parameters
One is mentioned above using 1 struct to hold all the return values inside struct.

Another is using pointer/address to hold the values.

I revised the script to show both ways. I will add a positive comment for HelloWorld, you guys are too harsh, it is an important concepts in c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define HIGH_NUMBER 100
typedef struct Random Random;
Random *isValidNumbers(int *num1,int *num2, int *num3);
struct Random{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main(void)
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    /* pr to use as parameter, rr used as a return struct , just for demoo purpuse*/
    Random *p;
    p = isValidNumbers(&num1,&num2,&num3);
    printf("%d %d %d main return random numbers\n",num1,num2,num3);
    printf("%d %d %d main return from struct   \n",p->a,p->b,p->c);
    return 0;
}

Random *isValidNumbers(int *num1,int *num2, int *num3)
{
    struct Random *r = malloc(sizeof(Random));
    int i=1,ans = 0;
    do
    {
        srand (time(NULL));
        *num1 = rand()%HIGH_NUMBER;
        *num2 = rand()%HIGH_NUMBER;
        *num3 = rand()%HIGH_NUMBER;
        r->a = *num1;
        r->b = *num2;
        r->c = *num3;

        if ((*num1%2==0||*num2%2||*num3%2==0)&&(*num1%2==1||*num2%2==1||*num3%2==1)&&(*num1>50||*num2>50||*num3>50))
        {
            i--;
            printf("%d %d %d inside isValidNumber\n",*num1,*num2,*num3);
            break;
        }
    }
    while (i);
    return r;
}
```

Results:

```
cmake28 ..
make
[gliang@www build]$ ./src/random
99 99 44 inside isValidNumber
99 99 44 main return random numbers
99 99 44 main return from struct
```