# Is using multiple function parameters for the purpose of returning multiple values in C bad practice?

Tags: c

If I have a function which calculates the minimum and maximum of an array would it be bad practice to include minimum and maximum in the function parameters so I can edit them while the function runs.

So I would have `void minmax(array, int min, int max)`

the min and max variables would be sent in as null and get changed when the function runs. Would this be ok or should I be using malloc to get an array and return the pointer instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829167/returning-multiple-values-from-a-function

Comment: How does `minmax()` know how big the array is?   There should probably be another argument to specify the number of entries in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: If I have a function which calculates the minimum and maximum of an array would it be bad practice to include minimum and maximum in the function paramiters

A: No, not at all.  That's a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Q: "So I would have `void minmax(array, int min, int max)`..."

A: Uh, no.  That would NOT pass "min" and "max" back to the caller.  Instead, you need something like:

`void minman(int * array, int * min, int * max);`'

For example:

```
int myarray[] = {1, 2, 3};
int min, max;
minman(myarray, &min, &max);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

That's totally fine, except that you'll need `min` and `max` to be pointers. If they're just plain old `int` like you have there, the caller will never see the changes you make.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with a function returning values through parameters. Except the code you wrote will not work - change it like this:

```
void minmax(int *array, int *min, int *max)
```

Also see [returning multiple values from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829167/returning-multiple-values-from-a-function).

Comment: If an answer starts with a disclaimer like "I don't think …", the question is off-topic as too  opinionated.

Comment: Or my answer shouldn't have started with "I don't think so " while the question is just fine.

Comment: @Olaf Edited my answer to remove any doubt.

Comment: That was not my point! The disclaimer was well justified. Just don't anser off-topic questions, but flag them. Help keeping up the quality of this site!

Comment: @Olaf I see... and I understand. However, in my opinion, sometimes this kind of questions are legitimate. For example, similar modification of input arguments in Python, while possible, is viewed well by some. A discussion of arguments for each use case is useful, in my opinion.

Comment: Please take this to meta. The question is clearly POB and there is a clear statement such questions are OT.