# Double returns in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to return two variables in C?

I would like to return a pointer as well as a string so that I can use both outside of the function.

Is this done with an array? if so, what type of array would it be? Void?

Comment: Many duplicates on SO already, for both C and C++, see e.g. [C - how do i return multiple values from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/c-how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can only return one object.  You can, however, return a struct type object and you can put your "multiple returns" into the struct:

```
typedef struct return_type
{
    void* pointer_; // You should, of course, use whatever the appropriate types
    char* string_;  // are for the objects that you are trying to return.
};

return_type f();
```

Comment: do you see any potential problem cluttering the namespace?

Comment: @Scott:  Not really, no.  I mean, you wouldn't want to actually name the structure `return_type`; if you have a function named `do_x` then you can name the return type structure `do_x_result` or something similar.

Comment: Great thanks. What is the return type for the function which returns this? Could I create one e.g. return_type *rt; rt->firstField = blah; rt->secondField = blahblah; in the function and set the return type to return_type * ? In the call to this function would I then create a pointer of the return_type e.g. return_type *data = functionReturningStruct ? it seems overkill and requiring many duplicates. Thanks

Comment: @alJaree:  Why would you return a `return_type*`?  Just return a `return_type` object; you can treat it like any other struct type object.

Comment: Im really confusing myself with pointers and structs. so I would set the struct as follows rs.firstField if its a basic struct object. But I would set it as rs->firstField if it was a pointer to a struct?

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1) Create a struct and return that

2) As parameters use pointers to what you want to change

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this,

```
void func(void **pVoid, char **szString)
{
    pVoid = 0x1234;
    szString = "Hello";
}

void* pVoid;
char* szString;
func(&pVoid, &szString);
```

Comment: Forgot to dereference your parameters in assignment.

Answer (score 0):

you can return one item from the function then take a pointer as an argument that you will change. If you are given a `char*` (to return a string) and you change the location it points to (don't forget to free if it's already allocated!) then the caller should see a changed value on the other end of the pointer as well. You can return a pointer as the main return value of the function.