# Returning multiple values from one function to another function

Tags: c, function, return

From the function below termspro I want to use coeff and power in another function and tried the following line but it would give me one value and the other as 0

//Term is an array of characters

```
int power,coef=termspro(term); 
 printf("POWER : %d\n",power);
 printf("COEF : %d\n",coef);

          int termspro(char term[20]){
    int i,m=0,j=0,coeff=0,power=0;
    char coef[10], powerr[10];
    char *p;
    memset(&coef[0],'\0',sizeof(coef));
    memset(&powerr[0],'\0',sizeof(powerr));
    int termLen=strlen(term);
    for(i=0;i<termLen; i++){
        if(term[i]=='-')
            m++;
        if((term[i]>='0'&&term[i]<='9')&&(term[i-1]!='^')&&(term[i-2]!='^')&&(term[i-3]!='^')&&(term[i-4]!='^')){
            coef[j]=term[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    //printf("this term's coef = %s\n",coef);
    int coefLen=strlen(coef);
    for(i=0;i<coefLen;i++){
        coeff= (coeff*10)+((int)coef[i]-48);
    }

    //To get the sign :
    if(m%2!=0)
        coeff*=-1;
    //THE COEF IS DAMN READYYYYYYY :D !!
    printf("COEF : %d\n",coeff);
    //To get the power :
    p=strchr(term,'^');
    char delm[2]="^";
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(powerr,p);
    }
    //printf("this term's power = %s\n",powerr);
    int powerLen=strlen(powerr);
    for(i=1;i<powerLen;i++){
        power= (power*10)+((int)powerr[i]-48);
    }
    printf("POWER : %d\n",power);
    return coeff,power;
}
```

Comment: In c you can't return multiple value. Go check out how to use pointers/arrays if you want to use that elsewhere. Or you can use and return a struct (: Tell if you want an example ... or check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return multiple values from a function in C. Alternative is to pass the pointer of a variable (which can hold the needed value) to the function as parameter. This way the calling function can get the value from the called function.

Another option is to make the return type a struct or pointer to struct, which can hold multiple values.