# The best way to return a result

Tags: c, arrays, char, return, c-strings

I wrote the following function. This function receives the address of a hex value e.g. 0x4571 and calculates with Day, Month and Year from the bit positions of the hex value.

```
void fat_dir_date(char *dateAr) {   

    const unsigned int MaskDayOfMonth = 0x1F; //0000000000011111
    const unsigned int MaskMonthOfYear = 0x1E0; //0000000111100000
    const unsigned int MaskYear = 0xFE00; //1111111000000000

    unsigned int DayOfMonth = hex & MaskDayOfMonth; //AND Bit Operation

    unsigned int MonthOfYear = hex & MaskMonthOfYear; //AND Bit Operation
    MonthOfYear = MonthOfYear >> 5; //Bitshift to right position

    unsigned int Year = hex & MaskYear; //AND Bit Operation
    Year = Year >> 9; //Bitshift to right position

    printf("%d.%d.%d", DayOfMonth, MonthOfYear, 1980+Year);
}
```

The calculation works fine. I get the right numbers in the integer DayOfMonth,MonthOfYear and Year. But instead of printing them out with printf, I want to return the values to the caller function. In the best way in concatenated in a single value or string.

How is the best way to solve this in C?

Comment: questions looking for the `best` way aren't suitable for S.O

Comment: Maybe you can put all of them in a `struct` which is created in heap, and return the address of that `struct`. Just my opinion though.

Comment: You have some strange definition of "works fine". The code does not even compile.

Comment: Assuming that `dateAr` points to a big enough buffer, you could use `sprintf` to put the result string into `dateAr`.

Comment: @self Is it wrong to explicitly ask for the best answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options there:

- Create a `struct` that has the three fields, and return it,
- Let the caller pass you the `struct` that you fill in,
- Let the caller pass you a string buffer to which you print using `sprintf`, or
- Create a string dynamically, print to it, and return.

The first option is clean and easy to understand. It requires some copying, but it is fine for small structures like the one that you need:

```
struct DateTime {
    int DayOfMonth;
    int MonthOfYear;
    int Year;
};
struct DateTime fat_dir_date(unsigned int hex) {
    struct DateTime res;
    res.DayOfMonth = ...
    res.MonthOfYear = ...
    res.Year = ...
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Why not `void fat_dir_date(unsigned int, unsigned int *, unsigned int *, unsigned int *)`? Why must "return" the value?

Comment: @user3528438 Because the three values are related. They represent a single logical thing, so it makes perfect sense to combine them in a single `struct`.

Comment: Probably one more option as well, not as favored, but nonetheless valid. Declare `fat_dir_date` as `char *`, and declare a static buffer in `fat_dir_date` of adequate size (e.g. `static char buf[12] = {0};`). Then using `sprintf` or your favorite conversion routine, fill and return `buf`. By declaring `buf` as `static`, `buf` continues to exist and provide a valid return.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'd rather not recommend this as an option at all, because it creates a non-reentrant function. Some legacy functions in the C library are like that (`strtok` is perhaps the most notorious of the bunch) but it creates headache down the road. One problem I see with functions returning static buffers is that the issues they create are hard to recognize: the code works flawlessly almost all the time!

Comment: Agreed, that is why I qualified it with **not as favored**, but noted it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: `DateTime struct` could be an argument, the function can return an `int`, this allows to check the integrity of the data. For example return `0` on sucess, `-1` if hex is not correct (day > 31, month > 12, etc...)

Answer (score -2):

If you need to print the data and you don't need to use the numeric values, I think this:

```
char * fat_dir_date(char *dateAr,unsigned int hex) {   

    const unsigned int MaskDayOfMonth = 0x1F; //0000000000011111
    const unsigned int MaskMonthOfYear = 0x1E0; //0000000111100000
    const unsigned int MaskYear = 0xFE00; //1111111000000000

    unsigned int DayOfMonth = hex & MaskDayOfMonth; //AND Bit Operation

    unsigned int MonthOfYear = hex & MaskMonthOfYear; //AND Bit Operation
    MonthOfYear = MonthOfYear >> 5; //Bitshift to right position

    unsigned int Year = hex & MaskYear; //AND Bit Operation
    Year = Year >> 9; //Bitshift to right position

    sprintf(dateAr,"%02u.%02u.%4u", DayOfMonth,MonthOfYear, 1980+Year);
    return dateAr;
}

int main(void)
{
    char dateAr[11];
    unsigned int hex=0x1010; //Random :)

    printf("%s\n" , fat_dir_date(dateAr,hex))

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, may be better!!! For security should be better also to don't use the printf and company!