# Functions in C, sending more than one value

Tags: c

Is that possible to send two values to function and return both separately without using data structures such as arrays?

like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int f(int a,int b)
{
    a*=2;
    b*=2;

    return ?????????
}

int main()
{
    int x=5,y=10,k;
    k=f(x,y) ?????????
    printf("%d",k);  ????????
}
```

Comment: You can pass the addresses of variables as a parameters in order the function to place some results there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly return more than one item (where an item could be a structure containing multiple items within). However you can "pass by reference" if you're comfortable with pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a *= 2;
    *b *= 2;
}
int main()
{
    int x=5, y=10;
    f(&x, &y);
    printf("new x: %d, new y: %d", x, y);
}
```

See the results of this at http://ideone.com/p4Xiqv

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to return more than one values without using any data structures. But, you can pass any number of arguments.