# Integer pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am very new to C programming and stackoverflow. I have a midterm tomorrow and I encountered this question while studying. Please accept my deepest apologies for my mistakes in regard to format.

Question : Write a function named: divide which takes two integers and an integer pointer. The function should divide the first integer to the second one, and return the result as an integer, and put the remainder into the address given by the integer pointer parameter.

The given main code reads two integers: a, b, and creates two integers without initialization: res, rem. Complete the function call so that the res variable become a/b, and rem variable become the remainder after the call.

Examples :

```
Input 12 5    Output 2 2  
Input 57 7    Output 8 1
```

The code that I wrote is :

```
int divide (int a , int b);  
int divide (int a , int b)
{  
    int res;  
    int rem;  
    res = a/b;  
    rem = a - res * b ;  
    return res, rem;  
}  

int main(void)
{  
    int a,b;  
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);  
    int res, rem;  
    res = divide(a,b);  
    printf("%d %d", res, rem);  
    return 0;  
}
```

When I run this, I get correct values for res but rem is always equal to zero. How can I use an integer pointer for rem value?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"a function which takes two integers and an integer pointer"* - your function only takes two integers. In C-like languages, when you need to return more than a single primitive value, you either define a `struct` which will hold these values, or return one or more values through pointer parameters. Tldr; your function prototype should be `int divide (int a, int b, int* rem)`.

Comment: You can use standard function [div](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div) instead of your `divide`. You should not make something that already exists.

Comment: In C, you can only return one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int divide (int a , int b, int* rem)
{  
    int res;  
    res = a/b;  
    *rem = a - res * b ;  
    return res;  
}  

int main(void)
{  
    int a,b;  
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);  
    int res, rem;  
    res = divide(a,b, &rem);  
    printf("%d %d", res, rem);  
    return 0;  
}
```

This should work.

1. You can't return multiple values from a function. `return res, rem;` will simply return rem due to comma operator.
2. To have multiple values seen at calling location, use pointers.

Comment: My guess is that it probably won't work, since you have a local variable named `rem`.

Comment: @Groo ..missed that, corrected. thanks

Comment: "You can't return multiple values from a function" --> True, yet a function can return a single `struct` (a single value) that contains 2 `int` values such as `div_t div(int numer, int denom);`

Comment: @chux agree, but OP mentioned function should return integer type and 3 arguments of which one should be integer pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also return a structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int quot;
    int rem;
} div_t;

div_t div( int numerator, int denominator )
{
    div_t result;
    result.quot = numerator / denominator;
    result.rem = numerator % denominator;

    return( result );
}
```

That is already implemented as [part of standard C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **7.22.6.2  The`div`, `ldiv`, and `lldiv` functions**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> div_t div(int numer, int denom);
> ldiv_t ldiv(long int numer, long int denom);
> lldiv_t lldiv(long long int numer, long long int denom);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `div`, `ldiv`, and `lldiv`, functions compute `numer / denom` and
>   `numer % denom` in a single operation.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `div`, `ldiv`, and `lldiv` functions return a structure of type
>   `div_t`, `ldiv_t`, and `lldiv_t`, respectively, comprising both the
>   quotient and the remainder.  The structures shall contain (in either
>   order) the members `quot` (the quotient) and `rem` (the remainder),
>   each  of  which  has  the  same  type  as  the  arguments `numer` and
>   `denom`. If either  part  of the result cannot be represented, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Note that calling `div()`, `ldiv()`, or `lldiv()` is likely much more efficient than computing both the quotient and remainder in two separate operations as most divide machine instructions produce both the quotient and remainder in two separate registers.

Comment: Interesting to see this answer is voted useful. It does not answer the question as it clearly ignores the requirement: **Write a function named: divide which takes two integers and an integer pointer.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is,

```
  return res, rem;
```

is the same as

```
 return rem;
```

due to the properties of [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) which is not what you expected.

You are supposed to

- pass a pointer to the `divide()` function to store the `rem` (remainder).
- return the result `res`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't [return multiple values in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)
The way you're doing you are just using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

There's some solutions presented on the link, you can return a struct or array containing all the values you want.

```
typedef struct your_return {
   int res;
   int rem;
} division_return;

division_return divide (int a , int b)
{  
    division_return ret;
    ret.res = a/b;  
    ret.rem = a - ret.res * b;
    return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    division_return dr;
    dr = divide(a,b);
    printf("%d %d", dr.res, dr.rem);
    return 0;
}
```

It's not a good practice to pass structs by value, as the copy can be expensive, but as you're new to the language I don't want to add more complexity to the code.
Unfortunately, C has no `references` as C++, which makes everything simpler.

You also can use pointers to change the value inside the function.

```
int divide (int a , int b, int* rem)
{  
    int res;  
    res = a/b;  
    *rem = a - res * b ;  
    return res;  
}
```

Comment: Note however, that passing structures by value is considered bad practice, since it is slow and eats stack memory.

Comment: Yes, I'll add it as a note, I just didn't want to add more complexity as the OP says he's new to the language and C has no `references` to make it easier.