# I am having issues understanding how to pass multiple values using structures in C

Tags: c, algorithm, return, structure

```
struct Tuple {
    int crossSum;
    int crossLow;
    int crossHigh;
};

struct Tuple findmaxcrossingsubarray(int A[], int low, int mid, int high){

int leftSum = -INFINITY;
int sum = 0;
int i;
int j;

int *crossLow;
int *crossHigh;
int *crossSum;

for ( j = mid; j == low; j--) {
  sum = sum + A[j];
  if (sum > leftSum)
      leftSum = sum;
      crossLow = &j;   //THIS COULD BE WRONG
}

int rightSum = -INFINITY;
sum = 0;

for (i = mid + 1; i == high ; i++) {
  sum = sum + A[j];
  if (sum > rightSum)
      rightSum = sum;
      crossHigh= &i;
}
    crossSum = crossLow + crossHigh;
}

void foo() {
  struct Tuple t = findmaxcrossingsubarray();
}
```

This is my function I need to pass crossSum, crossLow, and crossHigh to main where my other functions are.  This is an issue for all my functions.  I've seen how to do it but not with variables that are being used in loop statements.

I need to pass crossSum. crossLow, and crossHigh into my main function

Thanks for your time

Ryan

Comment: You don't have a structure in sight.

Comment: What is your question? What is your sample code supposed to do? Please go to [the how to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a question

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to return multiple values. (Note that `return(crossSum, crossLow, crossHigh);`.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: updated with an attempt