# How to return bool and double simultaneously?

Tags: c

In C, I have a function that calculates the product of a and b. If a < b it returns false otherwise returns true. How can I return the product when the function is defined as boolean?

```
bool multiplication(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a*b;
    if (a < b)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Your function name is very misleading. A function named `multiplication` implies that it's going to multiply, not return a boolean equality test.

Comment: Or you can use some `int*` parameters as output parameters.

Comment: It is a recursive function. So it returns boolean to specify when it ends.

Comment: "It is a recursive function. So it returns boolean to specify when it ends." In that case, you may want to update your example. I think this is somewhat of an x-y problem: the ending condition should happen naturally, and your function should be able to always return the same (double) type. Seeing the actual function, could help giving you better advice on how to implement such a function

Comment: You could also use 3 parameters, with the 3rd parameter being a reference. to another variable in the calling function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: by `double` do you mean `int` ?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer Yes, that's what I need.

Comment: Sorry, it works in C++ only, I missed the language tag when I clicked on your question. Consider using a struct instead.

Comment: The function in your question is not recursive, and there's no particular reason it should be. How is recursion relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are a few ways that come to mind that you can use to return a boolean and double simultaneously:**

1. Return the boolean as the return value and return the double as an output parameter.
2. Return a structure that has the boolean value as one field and the double value as another field.
3. Return the boolean value as the return value and return the double value using a global variable.

**Here's what code for these solutions respectively might look like:**

```
bool multiplication(int a, int b, double* product)
{
    *product = a * b;
    return a >= b;
}
```

And:

```
struct retval {
    bool b;
    double p;
}

struct retval multiplication(int a, int b)
{
    struct retval result;
    result.b = a >= b;
    result.p = a * b;
    return result;
}
```

And lastly:

```
double product;

bool multiplication(int a, int b)
{
    product = a * b;
    return a >= b;
}
```

Of these, the second solution doesn't fit your question exactly as it no longer returns a bool (but instead returns a `struct` which can have other downsides in C). The third solution, I despise because I strongly dislike the use of globals (globals make unit testing harder, keeps the using function from being able to be a pure function, causes threading issues).

So this leaves the first solution.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

> How to return bool and double simultaneously?

A function can only have one return type. But you can use a workaround of using a struct containing a bool and an int members as stated in one of the comments.

You can achieve your goal of writing a multiplication function of positive integers with a recursion logic the following way too:

```
int multiplication(int a, int b) {
    if(b <= 1) return a;
    return a + multiplication(a, --b);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the recursive method is relevant; the OP seems content with a function that uses the `*` operator.

Comment: @KeithThompson, yeah, I am not sure what exactly OP wants. But I will leave my answer here as is in case it might be helpful to the future users.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can define a new parameter as output.
2. define a struct included bool and int data. 
   Initiate the struct, then return it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean?