# C - Function which takes 2 floats and returns their difference after the block using pointers

Tags: c, function, difference

I'm trying to write a function which takes two generic floats (make it 'a' and 'b') and returns their difference assigned to the variables, so a=a-b and b=b-a.
It should print the values with 2 decimal places and it must work after I exit the block... What is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
float diff_abs (float *a, float *b) {
*a= *a-*b;
*b= *b-*a;
}

int main(void) {
    float c, d;
    scanf("%f", &c);
    scanf("%f", &d);
printf("%.2f\n%.2f", diff_abs(&c, &d));
return 0;   
}
```

I would appreciate your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: The problem is that the second calculations uses the new value of a. I would suggest doing `*b = -*a;`, because of how math works.

Comment: `which takes two generic floats`...1) what is a generic float? 2) a pointer != scalar variable.

Comment: Another problem is that your `diff_abs` function is supposed to return a `float` value, but it doesn't actually return anything.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are changing `a` value then using it to the next calculation so simplify change your function to:

```
void diff_abs (float *a, float *b) {
    *a= *a-*b;
    *b = -*a
}
```

Second, since you can't return multiple variables in a `C` function, one of the solution is to use `void` returning function but change variables while using pointers (like you're somehow doing)

Finally, since your function returns `void` you can't use it as `floats` in the `printf` function so just use `c` and `d`

like this:

```
printf("%.2f\n%.2f",c,d);
```

of course don't forget to call:

```
diff_abs(&c, &d)
```

before trying to print

you can refer to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c) for returning multiple variables in C