# error: conflicting types for 'components'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Can someone point out what i am doing wrong, i am very new to c programming.
I keep getting conflicting types for 'components' error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float Vo,ang;
    printf("Enter Velocity:");
    scanf("%f",&Vo);
    printf("Enter Angle:");
    scanf("%f",&ang);
    printf("The x component is %f and the y component is %f",components(Vo,ang));

}

float components(float Vo, float ang,float Vx, float Vy)
{
    Vx=Vo*cos(ang);
    Vy=Vo*sin(ang);
    return Vx,Vy;
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Apart from the compiler errors (solved in the answer below), let me mention that `return Vx,Vy;` is almost guaranteed not to do what you expect.

Comment: Your way of returning multiple values isn't correct. See [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2620146/1275169)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the definition of the called function before the place where you call it.
Or provide a prototype before main(), i.e. insert

```
float components(float Vo, float ang,float Vx, float Vy);
```

before

```
int main()
```

That way the compiler does not have to guess the type involved in calling that function. Since the compiler guesses incorrectly, it later complains about the types not matching. Changing the order of what the compiler sees when fixes that problem.

Also,

```
components(Vo,ang)
```

among your values provided to printf only gives one value, while printf() with your format string expects two.
You need to write the two separate values into two variables, which then are given to printf. You can for example give two more parameters to the function, pointers to suitable variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void components(float Vo, float ang, float* outpVx, float* outpVy)
{
    *outpVx=Vo*cos(ang);
    *outpVy=Vo*sin(ang);
}

int main(void)
{
    float Vo,ang;
    float outVx=0.0;
    float outvy=0.0;

    printf("Enter Velocity:");
    scanf("%f",&Vo);
    printf("Enter Angle:");
    scanf("%f",&ang);
    components(Vo,ang, &outVx, &outVy);
    printf("The x component is %f and the y component is %f", outVx, outVy);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: What if i now wanted to add this in the components function  x = vx.t         
,  y = vy*t + ½ at^2 where a= -9.81

Comment: Sorry? I do not get what you are asking. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: If you want to calculate (the) two values differently, i.e. with a different math expression, then what keeps you from editing the expressions used but keeping the way of returning the results?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean can you expand on that?

Comment: No I cannot. It is my guess at what you are trying to ask/tell me. If I guess incorrectly, then please you try to explain (differently) what I can help you with. But maybe you should make a separate new question of that anyway.

Comment: It's fine i have figured it out, thank you very much for your previous quick replies, really helped.