# Returning more than one variable in the same function

Tags: c

I just need help with returning two user input floating-point numbers using the same function. Can anyone show me how to return more then one variable? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIDE_1_LABEL 'A'
#define SIDE_2_LABEL 'B'

float getUserValue(float side1, float side2);

int main()
{
    float   side1,
            side2; 

    side1     = getUserValue(SIDE_1_LABEL);
    side2     = getUserValue(SIDE_2_LABEL);

    return 0;
}

float getUserValue(float side1, float side2)
{      
    printf(" Enter a value for Side %c.\n", SIDE_1_LABEL);
    printf("> ");

    scanf("%f", &side1); 

    printf(" Enter a value for Side %c.\n", SIDE_2_LABEL);
    printf("> ");

    scanf("%f", &side2);

    return side1, side2;
}
```

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Since both variables are of same datatype you can return array of floats. Another option is passing both variables as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either put the two floats into a struct that the function can return, or pass one (or both) floats in as a pass-by-reference parameter.  I would definitely prefer two pass-by-reference parameters in this case.

```
void getUserValue(float *side1, float *side2) {      
    printf(" Enter a value for Side %c.\n", SIDE_1_LABEL);
    printf("> ");

    scanf("%f", side1); 

    printf(" Enter a value for Side %c.\n", SIDE_2_LABEL);
    printf("> ");

    scanf("%f", side2);
}
```

There are other serious issues in your code, such as passing chars `A` and `B` in as the float parameters for `getUserValue()`, and only a single one for each call.  You should call `getUserValue()` as:

```
int main() {
    float   side1, side2; 

    getUserValue(&side1, &side2);

    return 0;
}
```

You don't need to pass in `SIDE_1_LABEL` and `SIDE_2_LABEL`, as they are #defined globally and can be accessed directly by `getUserValue()`.  And since you get both values in a single call, you don't need to call `getUserValue()` twice.

Another approach would be to have `getUserValue()` get only a single value at a time with:

```
float getUserValue(char label) {
    float side;

    printf(" Enter a value for Side %c.\n", label);
    printf("> ");

    scanf("%f", &side);

    return side;
}
```

then call it twice like you currently do :

```
side1     = getUserValue(SIDE_1_LABEL);
side2     = getUserValue(SIDE_2_LABEL);
```

Comment: Minor issue, `'A'` is an `int`. `printf(... , label);` promotes `label` to an `int`.  `printf("%c", label);` expects an `int` (which it converts to an `unsigned char` before printing).   No  real advantage to using `char label` whereas `int label` does better when a value outside the `[0...CHAR_MAX]` range is used.