# How can I return 2 numbers from a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, if-statement, return

I have to copy paste this exact code below into 3 separate functions (juice function, milk function and buy function). So I thought, why not make another function called array_checker and call it in toe juice, milk and buy function instead of the copy pasting the code. However, the function (copy pasted code) needs to return 2 things. int item_used and int buy_now. How can I do this?

This is the code I copy paste:

```
if (item_sale == 1) {
    item_used = TRUE;
    buy_now = legal_cards[0];
} else {
    item_used = FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches to this:

- **Create a `struct` with two `int` members to return from your function** - this is fine when two values that you return are easy to copy, e.g. a pair of `int`s, or
- **Take a pointer for one or both variables** - this lets you avoid copying, but requires the caller to allocate storage for the result upfront.

Here is an example of the first approach:

```
struct buy_decision {
    int item_used;
    int buy_now;
};

buy_decision milk(...) {
    buy_decision res;
    if (item_sale == 1) {
        res.item_used = TRUE;
        res.buy_now = legal_cards[0];
    } else {
        res.item_used = FALSE; 
        res.buy_now = 0;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here is an example of the second approach with `buy_now` taken by pointer:

```
int milk(..., int* buy_now_ptr) {
    if (item_sale == 1) {
        *buy_now_ptr = legal_cards[0];
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can return an array with both numbers.

Comment: You cannot return an array in C.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either define a structure to return :

```
struct itemStuff {
    int itemUsed;
    int buy_now;
}
```

then

```
struct itemStuff myItemFunction(...) {
    struct itemStuff myItem;

    (...)

    if (item_sale == 1) {
        myItem.item_used = TRUE;
        myItem.buy_now = legal_cards[0];
    } else {
        myItem.item_used = FALSE; 
    }

    return myItem;
}
```

The caller of the function will have to create the same struct to receive the return data

```
struct itemStuff thisItem = myItemFunction(...);
```

or use pass-by reference to pass in modifiable arguments

```
void myItemFunction(..., int *item_used, int *buy_noe) {
    if (item_sale == 1) {
        *item_used = TRUE;
        *buy_now = legal_cards[0];
    } else {
        *item_used = FALSE; 
    }
}
```

Here, the caller will have to pass in the address of two integers to be set :

```
int used;
int buy;

myItemFunction(..., &used, &buy);
```

Answer (score 0):

To return multiple values from a function, create one structure, put the member whatever you want into this & return the structure variable. for e.g

```
typedef struct buy_fun_info {
   int  item_used;
   int buy_now;
}BUY;
```

In `array_checker()` function, create the variable of above structure, fill the members & return those.  for e.g

```
BUY array_checker() { /*array_checker() function */
   BUY obj;
   obj.buy_now = legal_cards[0];
   obj.item_used = FALSE;

   return obj;/* return structure variable */   
}
```

Above I tried to explain with sample example, you need to modify accordingly.