# can't return the right variable in C

Tags: c

I want to try write Kadane algorithms using C. Instead of just return maximum subarray value, I also want to return the start and end index.

And here's the code :

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int kadane(int A[], int size){
    int current_max = INT_MIN;
    int global_max = INT_MIN;
    int start, last;

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        if (A[i] > A[i] + current_max){
            current_max = A[i];
            start = i;
        } else {
            current_max += A[i];
        };

        if (current_max >= global_max){
            global_max = current_max;
            last = i;
        };
    };
    return (start, last ,global_max);
}

int main(){
    int sum, size, start, last;
    int A[] = {3,-4,5,1,9,-10,11,2,5,-1,2};
    size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);

    start, last, sum = kadane(A, size-1);
    printf("start at %d ; end at %d; sum : %d\n", start, last, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Although the answer of maximum sum is right, the value of start and last are really weird. I use printf to check the value of start and last in the for loop of kadane function, and it seems work fine there. So I thought the problem might have something to do with the way I return variable.

so I modify some part of code like this :

```
int kadane(int A[], int size){
    ......
    ......
    return (&start, &last ,global_max);
}
```

and then using pointer to store them :

```
int main(){
    .......
    .......
    int *start;
    int *last;

    *start, *last, sum = kadane(A, size-1);
    printf("start at %d ; end at %d; sum : %d\n", *start, *last, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

then I got "Segmentation Fault 11" error.

I try to understand and search what I'm doing wrong here but I just can't find it.The only solution that work is to store variable start and last in global so that I can just call then anywhere without return.But I feel like that is not a suitable solution. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: You can't `return` more than one value in C

Comment: need to use pointers if yo want to return more 1 value

Comment: The loop condition `i <= size` will break array bounds of `int A[]` when `i == size`.

Comment: You should also turn your compiler's warning settings to the maximum (and turn on "treat warnings as errors"), it would have shown you that your code doesn't do what you want it to do

Answer (score 3):

You have two solutions:

1: Return a struct which contains all the types you need.

```
struct data {
    int start;
    int last;
    int global_max;
};
struct data kadane(int A[], int size){
    stuct data test = { 1, 1, 1 };
    ......
    ......
    return test;
}

void main() {
    ......
    struct data t = kadane(A, ize);
}
```

2: Use pointers to pass out values.

```
void kadane(int A[], int size, int *start, int *last, int *global_max) {
    ......
    ......
    *start = 1;
    *last= 1;
    *global_max= 1;
}

void main() {
    ......
    int a, b, c;
    kadane(A, size, &a, &b, &c);
}
```

> From
>   [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Please don't copy paste existing answers, that's what the "flag as duplicate" functionality is for