# Functions C won't print

Tags: c, function, printing

My program won't print out any value from the setAverage and largestNum variables. I get no errors in my compiler. What am I missing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 5

void arrayNumbers(float set_numbers[ROWS][COLS], int, int, float, float);
void inputData(float set_numbers[ROWS][COLS], int, int);

int main(){
  // 2D array of 15 numbers declaration and variables declared
  float set_numbers[ROWS][COLS], largestNum, setAverage;
  //counter variables for the loop
  int column, row;
  inputData(set_numbers, row, column);
  arrayNumbers(set_numbers, row, column, setAverage, largestNum);
      printf("\n");
      printf("\tThe total average of the set: %.1f\n", setAverage);
      printf("\tThe largest number in the array is: %.1f\n\n", largestNum);
  return 0;
  }

void inputData(float set_numbers[ROWS][COLS], int row, int column){
      printf("\tYou're given an array which is a 3-by-5 array.\n");
      printf("\tYou're going to put in each of the total 15 values.\n");
      printf("\t///////////////////////////////////////////////////\n");
  for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
    for(column = 0; column < COLS; column++){
      printf("\tAdd data to position [%d]:[%d]", row + 1, column + 1);
      scanf("%f", &set_numbers[row][column]);
    }
  }
      printf("\n\tYour entered values are: \n\n");
  for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
    for(column = 0; column < COLS; column++){
      printf("\t%.1f\t", set_numbers[row][column]);
    }
      printf("\n");
  }
}

void arrayNumbers(float set_numbers[ROWS][COLS], int row, int column,
                  float setAverage, float largestNum){
      printf("\t/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
      printf("//////////\n");
      printf("\n\tThe average of your 3-by-5 sets of numbers are: \n\n");
  float total, sum;
  for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
    for(column = 0; column < COLS; column++){
      sum = 0;
      sum = sum + set_numbers[row][column];
      total = total + set_numbers[row][column];
      setAverage = total / (COLS * ROWS);

      if(largestNum < set_numbers[row][column]){
          largestNum = set_numbers[row][column];
          }
        }
        printf("\n\tAverage of row [%d]: %.1f\t", row + 1, sum/COLS);
    }
  }
```

I can't seem to find the place, where I have missed af value or made the wrong calculations. It is the last thing I need before the program can be submitted for my engineering class. I checked some other stacoverflows but nothing useful came up.

Comment: Please format your code in some conventional way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiate either variables(setAverage, largestNum) to a beginning value. If they're garbage data, your inequality that's responsible for setting largestNum may never be true. The real issue though is [you're passing them by value](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/programming/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-visual-explanation.phphttps://www.mathwarehouse.com/programming/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-visual-explanation.php) and expect them to be updated when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

In the function arrayNumbers(set_numbers, row, column, setAverage, largestNum);
The setAverage and largestNum are being passed by value(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-by-pointer-vs-passing-by-reference-in-c/). so the values wont get updated.

in the arrayNumbers function, sum is placed inside the 2 loops. so the its just the last value of the row.

Answer (score 0):

To answer OP's question, I copied your code and run it on onlinegdb. It prompts me to enter the input 15 times which is what function *inputdata* does. The program is sitting there waiting for user's input if that is the question you are asking

> My program won't print out any value from the setAverage and
>   largestNum variables. I get no errors in my compiler. What am I
>   missing here

For this particular compiler it prints out 0s for both numbers as they are initialized to be 0s and like other said you will have to pass by pointer instead of doing a pass by value.