# How Do I Move my printf statement to my main driver?

Tags: c

This might be a dumb question but how do I move my `printf` statement from my `readfile` function to my `main` function while keeping my `if` statement intact? I kind of want to put a `return` there but I'm not to sure. Here's my code.

```c
int readfile( struct record somearray[ ], int *num, char filename[ ] )
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int count=0;
    char str_read[1000];
    fptr = fopen(filename , "r");

    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(str_read, sizeof(str_read) , fptr)!= NULL)
    {
        if((sscanf(str_read, "%d", &somearray->level)!=1) && (sscanf(str_read, "%s", pokesomearray->name)))
        {
            printf("level: %d\n name: %s\n", somearray->level, somearray->name);      
        }
        *num = ((count++)+1)/2;        
    }
        printf("The count is: %d\n", *num);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

here my main function

```
int readfile( struct record somearray[ ], int *num, char filename[ ] );

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num;
    char filename[]= "test_file.txt";
    struct record bank[5];
    int status_read = readfile( bank, &num, filename);

    if ( status_read != 0 )
    {
        printf("ERROR: Unable to read file");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Reading Accounts Successful\n\n");
        printf("level: %d\n", bank->level);
    }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you add the `main` function that you're using?  Then we can think about how to move the print statements outside of it.

Comment: sure, let me add that right now.

Comment: I assume you mean the `printf("The count is: %d\n", *num);`? Well, you are passing an `int*` into this function, so you can observe the value it points to after this function returns.

Comment: what do you mean? that loop may print multiple things. What's the difference between printing in the function and outside the function? The best you can do is return all the data from the loop for the main function to handle and print

Comment: @GSerg that's just me testing to see what prints.

Comment: @chase therein lies my problem. what am i exactly returning. can I return say return some array->level, some array->name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: @GSerg, thanks for the link however it really didn't help me much. It was way to complicated for what my homework was asking for. I was however able to figure it out just from sticking to the basics. Thank you tho, I really do I appreciate the help.