# Writing a function that solves the quotient and remainder in C

Tags: c

my assignment seems to not be working and I'm not sure why. I'm really new to C and I can't seem to get this to work. My teacher isn't very good so I don't know what to do with the pointer remainder or how to add both quotient and remainder into the return. I don't know how to fix any of this.

Here is my assignment:

[image: assignment]

Here is my code. I already know it's bad:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myDiv(int a, int b, int *remainder);

int myDiv(int a, int b) {

    int quotient = a / b;
    remainder = a % b;

    int answer = quotient, remainder;

    return (answer);
}


int main() {

    printf(" %d %d\n", myDiv(10, 5));

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
question3.c:5:5: error: conflicting types for 'myDiv'
 int myDiv(int a, int b) {
     ^~~~~
question3.c:3:5: note: previous declaration of 'myDiv' was here
 int myDiv(int a, int b, int *remainder);
     ^~~~~
question3.c: In function 'myDiv':
question3.c:8:5: error: 'remainder' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'rewind'?
     remainder = a % b;
     ^~~~~~~~~
     rewind
question3.c:8:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

I tried so hard but I can't. I'm simply not good at it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: THe check when b = 0 doesn't seem to be working. Here is the updated code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myDiv(int a, int b, int *remainder) {

    int quotient = a / b;
    *remainder = a % b;

    return (quotient);
}


int main() {

    int theQuotient, theRemainder;

    theQuotient = myDiv(10, 5, &theRemainder);
    printf("%d %d\n", theQuotient, theRemainder);

    theQuotient = myDiv(-9, 4, &theRemainder);
    printf("%d %d\n", theQuotient, theRemainder);

    theQuotient = myDiv(0, 12, &theRemainder);
    printf("%d %d\n", theQuotient, theRemainder);

    theQuotient = myDiv(17, 0, &theRemainder);
    printf("%d %d\n", theQuotient, theRemainder);

    if (theQuotient = 0) {

        theQuotient, theRemainder = 0;
        printf("%d %d\n", theQuotient, theRemainder);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int answer = quotient, remainder;` does not do what you think.  Look up the comma operator.

Comment: @NateEldredge Then how do I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C doesn't allow you to define the same function with multiple prototypes. You need to define just one, that takes the `int *remainder`, and pass it along. The third argument is used to pass back the extra return value, and you need to declare storage for it, and pass the address of said storage to the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myDiv(int a, int b, int *remainder) {

    int quotient = a / b;
    *remainder = a % b;    // Store remainder to caller provided storage

    return quotient;       // Return quotient directly
}

int main() {
    int quo, rem;
    
    quo = myDiv(10, 5, &rem);  // Pass address of rem so myDiv can fill it in
    printf(" %d %d\n", quo, rem);

    return 0;
}
```

`int answer = quotient, remainder;` was never going to work; it's trying declare variables named `answer` (initialized with `quotient`) and `remainder` (uninitialized, but which you should have received as an argument).

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me out a lot and I realized how dumb answer = quotient, remainder is. Although, I have two questions. First of all, why doesn't it give the output for the fourth one? In the problem I have to find the answer to 10, 5 then -9, 4 then 0, 12 then 17, 0. I got 2 0, -2 -1, 0 0 for the outputs (that I am assuming is correct) but I didn't get an output for the fourth one. My second question is, what did my teacher mean by defensive programming? Thank you!

Comment: @mmno: The answer to both questions is basically the same. I did the minimum amount to make your code work, but it will fail when the divisor (`b`) is `0`, because dividing by `0` doesn't make sense (how do you split a number into groups of `0` each?). Basically, you need to check for `b` being `0` and handle it as a special case (perhaps by returning `0` for both quotient and remainder, perhaps printing an error and calling `exit(1);`, or something else appropriate). Defensive programming means thinking about how the code could fail and making sure you handle it in a reasonable way.

Comment: Ohh I get it now. Thank you!!

Comment: @mmno: You should ask a separate question when the thrust of the question changes dramatically, but short version: This check should be in `myDiv` (to defend it against bad inputs), not in `main` (which already knows what values it has, and should just not pass bad ones aside from illustrating a point). And you tested with `=` (which doesn't actually test, it assigns), not `==` (which tests for equality).