# How to return variables from my function to my main

Tags: c

The instructions say that I need to have my Categorize_temperatures function return the hot, cold, and pleasant values to my main function so that my main function can print them out. Right now I just have it so the Categorize_temperatures function prints out the values. How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>



int c = 0;
int temperatures[25];
int Categorize_temperatures();



int main(void)
{   
    int hot = 0;
    int pleasant = 0;
    int cold = 0;

    Categorize_temperatures(hot,pleasant,cold);
    return 0;
}



int Categorize_temperatures(int hot,int pleasant,int cold)
{
    for(c = 0; c<25; c=c+1)
    {
        printf("Please type the daily high temperature:");
        scanf("%d", &temperatures[c]);

        if(temperatures[c]>84)
        {
            printf("%d hot\n",temperatures[c]);
            hot = hot + 1;
        }
        if(temperatures[c]<85 && temperatures[c]>59)
        {
            printf("%d pleasant\n", temperatures[c]);
            pleasant = pleasant + 1;
        }
        if(temperatures[c]<60)
        {
            printf("%d cold\n", temperatures[c]); 
            cold = cold + 1;
        }
    }
printf("Hot days: %d\nPleasant days: %d\nCold days: %d\n", hot, pleasant, cold);
return 0;
}
```

All of it works correctly, I just need to try to return the `hot`, `pleasant`, and `cold` values to main so that I can print them.

Every attempt I have made to return the values and then print in main just ends up giving me values of 0 for `hot`, `pleasant`, and `cold`

When you run the program it will look like this:

*Please type the daily high temperature:*

*>50*

*50 cold*

Then it will ask for 24 more temperatures until there is an array of 25 temperatures and will print this at the end depending on the temperatures:

*Hot days: 5*

*Pleasant days: 15*

*Cold days: 5*

Comment: The function can accept a pointer to a struct or pointers for each individual result or return a struct.

Comment: Examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c-or-cpp/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: It seems that you want your function change data passed to it. Try [pass by reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzarg/cplr233.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 2 options.

1. Set your values into a struct and return that.

```c
struct temps
{
   int hot,cold,pleasant;
}temp_cat;
.
.     //Do stuff
.
return temp_cat;
```

2. You can take address of an array as input to the function and modify that.

```c
int temps[3];   //temp[0]-hot,[1]-cold,[2]-pleasant

// Do stuff

int Categorize_temperatures(temps);


// Defintion 
int Categorize_temperatures(int temps[])
{
//Do stuff
}    //No need to return
```