# C: warning returning void * from a function with return type in makes integer from pointer without cast

Tags: c, integer, void

I am writing a program to solve Sudoku puzzles using a backtracking algorithm when i compile my code the compiler returns a warning that states the following this is in the function find_empty_box()

```
warning: returning ‘void *’ from a function with return type ‘int’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

I have tried initialising the function as void * (i have also tried initialising it as int but this causes the warning about returning NULL which indicates i should declare the function as void * it does solve the previous warning but creates two other warnings the first warning is caused in the function find_empty_box() the second warning is caused in Solver()

```
warning: returning ‘int’ from a function with return type ‘void *’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   13 |                                 return x, y;

warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘void *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   78 |         row, col = find_empty_box(sudoku);
```

The Code for the program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int find_empty_box(int sudoku)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 9; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y)
        {
            if (sudoku[&x][&y] == 0)
            {
                return x, y;
            }
        }
        return NULL, NULL;
    }
}

int Answer_Valid(int sudoku, int guess, int row, int col)
{
    int row_values = sudoku[&row];

    for (int i = 0; i < sudoku[&row]; ++i)
    {
        if (guess == sudoku[&row[&i]])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int column_values = sudoku[&col];

    for (int t = 0; t <= 9; ++t)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < sudoku[&col]; ++n)
        {
            if (&guess == &sudoku[&col[&n]])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    int row_start = (row / 3) * 3;
    int col_start = (col / 3) * 3;

    for (int x = 0; x <= row_start && row_start + 3; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < col_start && col_start + 3; ++y)
        {
            if (sudoku[&x][&y] == guess)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}


int Solver(int sudoku, int guess, int row, int col)
{
    int grid[9][9] = 
    {
        {8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,7,0,0,9,0,2,0,0},
        {0,5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,4,5,7,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6,8},  
        {0,0,8,5,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,9,0,0,0,0,4,0,0}
    };

    row, col = find_empty_box(sudoku);

    if (&row == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; (i < 1)||(i < 2)||(i < 3)||(i < 4)||(i < 5)||(i < 6)||(i < 7)||(i < 8)||(i < 9); ++i)
    {
        if(Answer_Valid(sudoku, guess, row, col))
        {
            sudoku[&row][&col] = guess;

            if(Solver(sudoku, guess, row, col))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    int LineNum = 9;
    int RowAmount = 9;

    for (int i = 0; i < LineNum; ++i)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < RowAmount; ++t)
        {
            printf("%d ", grid[i][i]);
        }

        printf("\n");   
    }
}

int main()
{
    int grid[9][9] = 
    {
        {8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,7,0,0,9,0,2,0,0},
        {0,5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,4,5,7,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6,8},  
        {0,0,8,5,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,9,0,0,0,0,4,0,0}
    };

    int LineNum = 9;
    int RowAmount = 9;

    for (int i = 0; i < LineNum; ++i)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < RowAmount; ++x)
        {
            printf("%d ", &grid[i][x]);
        }

        printf("\n");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Functions can only have one return value in C. And it is not clear why you attempt to use `void *` to return an integer; as the compiler tells you these are not compatible types. To return an integer the return type would be `int`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return multiple values from a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: `return x, y;` does not do what you think it does. That is the same as `return y;`. The comma operator always evaluates to the last expression. It's not returning multiple values as you want it to. See the duplicate post for correct ways to do that.

Comment: Too pythonic for C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the error is pretty self-explanatory (you declare the function as returnin a `void*` but you're trying to return a pair of ints), the underlying problem is that C doesn't support 'pairs' or 'tuples' like this, so you're probably better off using additional pointer arguments to return these values, and just use the return value for a succeed/fail boolean flag.  So your `find_empty_box` function becomes:

```
bool find_empty_box(int sudoku[9][9], int *row, int *col)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 9; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y)
        {
            if (sudoku[x][y] == 0)
            {
                *row = x;
                *col = y;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You would then call this as

```
if (!find_empty_box(grid, &row, &col)) {
    ... could not find an empty box, done?
```

---

This brings up another problem -- you want to be passing `grid` around (not clear what `sudoku` is elsewhere), but it is an array, so it is effectively passed by reference (implicit pointer), so any changes you make in a function will affect the caller's `grid`.  Which may or may not be what you want.  The references you have to `sudoku[&x][&y]` are total nonsense -- they will likely just crash and won't do anything useful.

Comment: You forgot to put a semicolon at the end of *col = y

Comment: I have tried your code but i am getting a number of errors when compiling it the errors are

warning: passing argument 1 of ‘find_empty_box’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   81 |         row, col = find_empty_box(sudoku);
note: expected ‘int * (*)[9]’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    6 | bool find_empty_box(int *sudoku[9][9], int *row, int *col)
error: too few arguments to function ‘find_empty_box’
   81 |         row, col = find_empty_box(sudoku);
note: declared here
    6 | bool find_empty_box(int *sudoku[9][9], int *row, int *col)

Comment: The problem is the `sudoku` argument in solver doesn;t make any sense -- what is it supposed to be?  You probably mean to pass `grid`, but you should get that from `main` as well.