# How can I return multiple values without using arrays or pointers or structures?

Tags: c, function, return-value, return-type

We were given a source code to convert decimal to binary and octal.This is the source code that I am going to use the function Dec2BinOct() to return the values of the converted decimal.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long n, place=1, bin=0, r, o=0, place2=place;  
    printf("Conversion: Decimal to binary and octal.\n");
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%lu", &n);
    printf("%lu is ", n);
           
    for(unsigned long g = n; g != 0; place = place * 10)  {  
        r = g % 2;    
        bin = bin + (r * place);
        g = g / 2;  
    }  
    
    printf("%lu in Binary Form. \n", bin);
                
    printf("%lu is ", n);
    while (n != 0) {
        o = o + (n % 8) * place2;
        n =   n / 8;
        place2 = place2 * 10;
    }
    printf("%lu in Octal Form.\n\n", o);
    return 0;
}
```

We were tasked to apply functions for our assignment and were required to use the function Dec2BinOct() as stated earlier, but our teacher told us that it is the minimum required function. I don't seem to get the right program after so many tries. I just needed some help and this is due tomorrow. I appreciate all of your help

Comment: In C it does not exist the concept of multiple values, you implement it using some structures you enumarated.

Comment: In order to return multiple values, you need either pointers (either as argument to the function or as return type, if they have long enough lifetime), or either a structure (either by value as a return type, or by reference as an argument to the function).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620146/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just what is the `Dec2BinOct` function? We don't have access to  your homework assignment.

Comment: What is the range of the decimal number? Since your shown version without a function transfers this into another number that resembles binary if output as decimal, this is important to know. You can think of putting both results in a single `unsigned long`, returning this as a "multi-valued" single value.

Comment: Also, the assignment doesn't make any sense, since all numbers in your program is binary, period. They may be expressed in other bases in the source code, for programmer convenience, or they may be expressed in other bases when presented to the user. Maybe the assignment is to convert a number into a _string_ in a certain base? Also notably, BCD and similar is not binary is not decimal... this appears to be "DCB". Which isn't a very helpful format for any purpose.

Comment: Also, using `scanf()` to read (potentially malformed) user input without checking return code. Your `n` might be uninitialized. Better get into the habit of reading user input a line at a time (`fgets()`) and then checking the string with `strtol()` et al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want multiple values but not *at once*, you can just generalize both operations and provide base to which a number should be converted:

```
unsigned long Dec2AnotherBase(unsigned long n, int base){
    unsigned long place=1, result=0;
    for(; n; place*=10, n/=base) 
        result += n % base * place;
    return result;
}
```

In your main function you replace your loops with those:

```
bin=Dec2AnotherBase(n, 2);
o=Dec2AnotherBase(n, 8);
```

I also simplified your code a little. Here's what I did:

- Replaced `bin=bin+(r*place)` and `place=place*10` with shorter `bin+=r*place` and `place*=10`.
- Eliminated `r` variable because it's only used once (also no brackets around `%` are needed as `%` operator is the same precedence as `*` and evaluated left-to-right).
- Moved `g=g/2` inside increment statement using `,` operator.
- Removed curly brackets which were no longer required in a loop reduced to a single statement.
- Removed `g` since it is created unnecessarily (you can operate directly on `n` as it is already a copy of a variable passed to the function).
- *Contentious:* Replaced `n!=0` in condition with `n` as every non-zero value is implicitly converted to logical true.

Comment: On replacing `g != 0` by `g`, it's bad, better be clear than concise. Many professional code styles turn down such expressions. Code is read so much more than written, don't exchange one second of typing for many minutes of thinking.

Comment: This is really helpful huhuhu. Thank you so much!